# System doesn't boot using grub anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Well after closing the system down yesterday I open my pc and notice it immediatelly goes into "disk check utility" (Haven't seen that since windows xp times). However running it showed no problems and I rebooted as required.

I notice however that instead of going "purple" the screen stays black and goes directly to the windows-spinner indicating windows is being launched.
Another thing that I notice is that the warning "secure boot is off" no longer displays before the MSI boot screen.

So to fix it I first looked for the secure boot option, and secure boot is most certainly "disabled" (and settings is "standard"), so that is kind of surprising. But more importantly I tried to change the windows boot manager to grub by:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

And I rebooted with both secure boot off, and the forced bootmanager. To no avail, still nothing pops up and it boots directly into windows. To verify I typed `bcdedit /enum` which shows:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume5
path                    \EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  nl-NL
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {72434327-0dad-11eb-a1f2-e020679bdf22}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
```

So what is the cause of the boot manager to not pop up? How would I further trouble shoot this?

The big "weird" thing is that in the boot menu of the bios it only notices (twice) windows boot manager for the UEFI disks. I'm not really sure that is supposed to happen?

---

In the boot order I see those options:

```
Boot option #1 [CD/DVD]
Boot Option #2 [USB CD/DVD]
Boot option #3 [Hard Disk:Windows Boot manager]
Boot Option #4 [USB Hard Disk]
Boot option #5 [USB key]
Boot option #6 [Network:UEFI: IP4 Qualcom]
```

No option for the ubuntu or grub boot manager it seems?

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but does your BIOS boot priority point to the volume where Ubuntu was installed?  Can you provide more identifying information about the "disk check utility"?  Does it look like it belongs to Windows or Ubuntu?  If you're not sure, upload a screenshot to Imgur and link it in your post.  It's also not clear if you actually have Windows installed on your system.  Is this a dual boot configuration?

Comment: The disk checking is I think from windows, as it only checked the drives  though it happens before the os has loaded (and did only happen once, can't repeat that). It's just the thing where it says "checking sectors.... fixing bad sectors ...." (apart from no fixing necessary). The load order indeed only shows windows, but clicking on it doesn't allow me to change the drive there is no D drive possible. -- I have to state that it did work for at least 4 years, and nothing has changed since yesterday not even an update on either windows or ubuntu.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "D drive" in your BIOS or Ubuntu. Letter drives are a label that Windows uses.  In your BIOS, there's no choice for Ubuntu or the volume where Ubuntu is located?  Can you boot Ubuntu as a liveCD from installation media and post a screenshot of the partitions on your disk(s) from the "Disks" application in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Nmath sorry, indeed it is "Hard disk:Windows" which is the partition labelled "C" and on the main physical hard drive. I have two in my laptop, one which houses windows on a 150gb ssd and a secondary 1tb -nowadays ssd- which is split into two partitions one containing ubuntu and one partition with media. I've updated with the exact naming from the boot manager. (I could upload a photograph but that's hard to read due to moire).

Comment: Based on your transcription of your boot options, I don't see any other bootable hard disk except for Windows.  I still think it would be helpful to provide the requested screenshot of your disk partitions as they appear in the "Disks" application from the liveUSB session.  There's no moire in a screenshot. There's no need to take a picture from your phone when you can just take a screenshot

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow then :)